# How to create Set of Hashable in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, set, swift2, protocols

I'm trying to create a `Set` of `Observer`s using the following code:

```
protocol MyProtocol: Hashable {
    typealias ConcreteType = Self

    var identifier: String { get }
}

extension MyProtocol {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return identifier.hashValue
    }
}

func ==<T: MyProtocol>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
    return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
}

protocol Observer: Equatable, Hashable {
    func identifierChanged<T: MyProtocol>(conformant: T)
}

extension Observer {
    func identifierChanged<T: MyProtocol where T == T.ConcreteType>() {} //Optional implementation
}
```

However I get the following error whenever I try to create a `Set<Observer>` (i.e. `let observerSet = Set<Observer>()`):

> Using 'Observer' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'Hashable' is not supported
>
> Protocol 'Observer' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can not create a collection that handles objects conforming to a Swift protocol. If a protocol uses `Self` in any place, you can no longer use it as a type, only as a type constraint. In your case `Self` is used in the assignment operator function which is required by the `Hashable` protocol.

I would recommend using a class instead of a protocol in this case.

Some more information on this issue can be found in this blog post and associated posts: http://inessential.com/2015/08/05/swift_diary_9_where_im_stuck

Comment: I would like to have several classes conforming to that protocol and some of  them already have other superclasses, I'm afraid I can't use classes instead of protocols at this moment.

Comment: I think the only other solution at the moment is to use @objc protocols then, but in that case you can not make it Hashable and you would need to use NSSet instead of a Swift Set.